# Lines and Planes

Tags: geometry

can someone please help me? How can I find the equation of the plane which contains the line

$r:$ $ x= 2 + 2\lambda$

$ y= 3 - \lambda$

$ z= -3\lambda$

($\lambda$ is a Real number)

and makes an angle of $\pi$/4 with the line

$ s:$ $x= 1 - 2t $

$y= 2 - t$

$z=3 - t$

(t is a Real number)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Start by accumulating some constraints on a normal vector to the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\vec n$ be a vector normal to the plane.

$r$ is parallel to the vector $\vec v_r = (2,-1,-3)$.

$\vec n\cdot \vec v_r = 0$.

$s$ is parallel to the vector $\vec v_s = (-2,-1,-1)$.

$\displaystyle \vec n \cdot \vec v_s = \frac{\Vert \vec n\Vert \Vert \vec v_r\Vert}{\sqrt 2}=\Vert \vec n\Vert \sqrt 3$

Breaking $\vec n$ down into its components turns this into a system of two equations with three unknowns, which is exactly what you need.